# Tag Helper in TemplateEditor doesn't bind depending on TemplateEditor's location

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm using areas to divide up my application and everything works as expected, including an EditorTemplate -- but only if the editor template in a certain location.  My Project works when it is setup like this (note the location of MyEditor.cshtml):

```
\Areas\Area1\Controllers\TestController.cs
\Areas\Area1\Views\Test\Index.cshtml
\Areas\Area1\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\MyEditor.cshtml
```

I am using an EditorTemplate (`MyEditor.cshtml`) inside `MyViewIndex.cshtml` and it works fine when I put it in the location listed above.

I can then move `MyEditor.cshtml` to the following location where MVC finds it, but doesn't render the Tag Helpers:

```
\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\MyEditor.cshtml
```

So instead this Tag helper...

```
<input asp-for="Hello1" type="text" />
```

...rendering like this:

```
<input value="ABC" type="text" id="Hello1" name="Hello1" />
```

...it's output to the browser like it was never processed:

```
<input asp-for="Hello1" type="text" />
```

Inside the view Index.cshtml I have:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Hello1, "MyEditor")
```

Inside MyEditor.cshtml I have:

```
Hello<br/>
@DateTime.Now<br/>
<input asp-for="OneEditorProperty1" type="text" />
```

I know it's finding the editor template because it outputs "Hello" and I know it's processing it to some degree because I see the DateTime.Now value. For some reason the Input Tag Helper doesn't get processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is missing from my question is where I have my @addTagHelper directives.

I had them here:

```
Areas\Area1\Views\_ViewImports.cshtml
```

But not here:

```
Views\_ViewImports.cshtml
```

I forget I even had to have this -- thanks to @dougbu over at https://github.com/aspnet for pointing this out.